# Scrolling elements then fixed

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, fixed

I can't seem to figure out a way to do this. I've found several example to get an element fixed when past a certain point but not multiple items overlapping.

Here's how I want want my site : https://jsfiddle.net/42q4go5L/5/

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
el = $(".wrapper");
wrapperOffset = el.offset().top; 
scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
if (wrapperOffset < scrollPosition){
    el.css("position", "fixed");
    el.css("top", "0");
}else{
    el.css("position", "relative");
    el.css("top", "100%");
}
```

})

What I want is when the div 2 reach the top of the page, it switches to fixed. Then when the div 3 reach the top, it get fixed, and so on...

My first div is fixed so you can already see the result I'm looking for. Maybe the way I've setup my html/css won't work either. I'm just starting with javascript so don't judge too much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using waypoints to fix elements at set positions on scroll, you will find it's very simple to use and also has a shortcut for sticky elements.

Documentation here:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Shortcut:

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

**EDIT:**

Use for multiple waypoints...

```
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    $(this).waypoint(function() {
        //do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know how if I can apply the same way point on multiple items automatically ? They're using document.getElementById('basic-waypoint') in the example. I'm trying to avoid doing it for every DIVs as content will be added through a CMS. Is the're another selector I could use ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly try this. It should iterate through each .waypoint element and add individual waypoints to each one. See edit.

Comment: Yeah that was kind of easy :P Thank you very much, that should do it !